# Run Java ScreenGrabber example

Tags: java, jmf, screen-grab

I'm trying to test the [Screen Grabber sample](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/screengrabber-178281.html) from JMF. Could anyone tell me how to write the main method to run this example?.

I have reviewed a lot in Google and have not found a way to make it work. because I do not know which of the two classes (LiveStream or DataSource) I must to use in the main method.

otherwise, I tried running the command:

```
java JMStudio screen://0,0,160,120/10
```

But it shows me the following exception:

```
UNABLE_CREATE_PLAYER*javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :screen://0,0,160,120/10
```

Thanks for the help.

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

### Don't.

JMF never really worked out and has been abandon.  ([Google: "JMF is dead"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jmf%20is%20dead).) Find another mechanism for screen grabbing.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I think and hope that Oracle will continue with the development of the JMF or develop an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

it's a late answer, but with the same hopes as Lobo, i'd like to add some constructive info :

1) JMF is old but also an old gun. it's working

2) it's pure Java, and if you are a Java guy, it will be helpful, this way or that way

3) use the methods you mentioned, if you can. follow the tutorial. otherwise, there is a free package that can be downloaded from http://www.kemottron.com, MODERATOR-CONFERENCE, you can try. pure Java, and it captures your desktop and broadcast to the Internet.

regards,